# Android Calendar problem with day of the week

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to list all days of the week for current week from Monday to Sunday. For example, today (day of this posting) is September 4th, 2011 and it's Sunday.

I'm starting calendar and setting first day of the week to Monday:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
```

When I check day of the month, I get correct result:

```
int check = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
// check is equal to 4
```

But when I set weekday to Monday, it jumps to the next week instead of returning Monday of this week:

```
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
int mon = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
// mon is equal to 5, when expected to be 29 (last Monday of August)
```

Even setting weekday to Sunday returns next Sunday and not today.

Can someone explain why it works that way and what's the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, when I check my own tests, it seems to work as expected, **except when the date is not set again**:

**Display 4-29**:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
cal.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4);
cal.set(2011, 8, 4);
int test = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
int mon = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
bTest.setText("" + test + "-" + mon);
```

**Display 5-5**:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
cal.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4);
cal.set(2011, 8, 5);
int test = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
int mon = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
bTest.setText("" + test + "-" + mon);
```

**Display 14-12**:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
cal.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4);
cal.set(2011, 8, 14);
int test = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
int mon = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
bTest.setText("" + test + "-" + mon);
```

So, this doesn't work:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
cal.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4);
//cal.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
int test = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
int mon = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
bTest.setText("" + test + "-" + mon); // Display 4-5
```

and **this works**:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
cal.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4);

// Workaround
cal.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

int test = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
int mon = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
bTest.setText("" + test + "-" + mon); // Display 4-29
```

and **this works** too:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
cal.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4);

// Workaround
cal.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
int mon = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
bTest.setText("" + mon); // Display 29
```

But this one doesn't:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
cal.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4);

// Workaround
cal.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
int mon = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
bTest.setText("" + mon); // Display 5
```

Comment: There's probably something which is done during the set which misses when directly using the instance..

Comment: Thank you, I was just about to write that setting date manually works as expected, cheers!

Comment: could you please do me one more favor and run your test without `int test = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);`? If I do that - the code breaks again on second `cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)`. It's not a big deal but I don't understand why this would be happening.

Comment: Thanks, glad to know I'm not the only one. I'll try to investigate this further.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Use `LocalDate`, never `Calendar`.

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )
    .with( TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) )
    .plusDays( i ) )
```

## java.time

Avoid the troublesome old legacy class `Calendar` as it is now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes (specifically [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)).

For date-only values without time-of-day, use `LocalDate` rather than a date+time type like `Calendar` or [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) implicitly applies its current default [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone). That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

### `DayOfWeek`

For day-of-week, use the `DayOfWeek` enum class. It offers seven instances, one for each day of the week, Monday-Sunday.

```
DayOfWeek dow = ld.getDayOfWeek() ;  // Get an enum representing the day-of-week of this date, such as `DayOfWeek.MONDAY`.
```

### Adjusting date

We need find the previous Monday, or stick with today’s date if already a Monday. To move to such dates, use the `TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame` implementation of `TemporalAdjuster`.

```
TemporalAdjuster ta = TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ;
LocalDate previousOrSameMonday = ld.with( ta ) ;
```

Collect your desired dates by incrementing with a call to [`LocalDate.plusDays()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusDays-long-). Notice how *java.time* uses [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). We get a fresh object based on the values of the original rather than *mutating* (altering) the original.

```
// Hard-coded `7` is the seven days in a week.
List< LocalDate > dates = new ArrayList<>( 7 ) ;
for( int i = 0 , i < 7 , i ++ ) {
    LocalDate localDate = previousOrSameMonday.plusDays( i ) ;
    dates.add( localDate ) ;
}
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

---

**UPDATE:** The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. This section left for history.

## Joda-Time

> what's the best way to solve this problem?

The best way is to avoid using the notoriously troublesome java.util.Date & .Calendar classes, and instead use the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library. Joda-Time works in Android.

Joda-Time offers the [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class for date-only values without any time or time zone.

### Example Code

Here is some example code using Joda-Time 2.3.

```
LocalDate localDate = new LocalDate( 2011, DateTimeConstants.SEPTEMBER, 4 );
LocalDate firstDateOfWeek = localDate.withDayOfWeek( DateTimeConstants.MONDAY );
for ( int i = 0; i < 7; i++ ) {
    LocalDate someDateOfWeek = firstDateOfWeek.plusDays( i );
    System.out.println( "someDateOfWeek: " + someDateOfWeek + "  le jour de la semaine: " + someDateOfWeek.dayOfWeek().getAsText( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) );
}
```

When run…

```
someDateOfWeek: 2011-08-29  le jour de la semaine: lundi
someDateOfWeek: 2011-08-30  le jour de la semaine: mardi
someDateOfWeek: 2011-08-31  le jour de la semaine: mercredi
someDateOfWeek: 2011-09-01  le jour de la semaine: jeudi
someDateOfWeek: 2011-09-02  le jour de la semaine: vendredi
someDateOfWeek: 2011-09-03  le jour de la semaine: samedi
someDateOfWeek: 2011-09-04  le jour de la semaine: dimanche
```

### Week Number

Bonus tip: If you want the week number as defined by the ISO 8601 standard, call the [`weekOfWeekYear`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#weekOfWeekyear%28%29) method. Like this:

```
int weekNumber = firstDateOfWeek.getWeekOfWeekyear();
```

Your date is in week 35.

Answer (score 0):

Humans must not use language of android beings, just kidding, date entering, is another one nail to java coffin.
core of this misunderstanding problem is bad documentation and two facts, months numbered from 0, and year counts from 1900, but not in Calendar and his descendants.
and one more fact, in Date Sunday is 0, but in Calendar Sunday is 1.

```
//THIS WORKS CORRECTLY
Date my = new Date(1986 - 1900, 04 - 1, 26);
System.out.println(my);
System.out.println(my.getDay());

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
cal.set(1986, 04 - 1, 26);
System.out.println(cal.getTime());
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)-Calendar.SUNDAY);
```

another, much more convenient way

```
//ONE AND ONLY, HUMAN FRIENDLY WAY TO ENTER DATE INTO JAVA
String date = "1986-04-26:01:23:47";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:SS");
Date convertedDate = (Date) formatter.parse(date);
System.out.println(convertedDate);
```

quite simple, is not it?